# Console error, preventDefault when scrolling over dxo-lookup in DevExtreme

Tags: angular

I am using the DevExtreme library and I have a dx-data-grid and its respective columns, inside one of them I have a dxo-lookup that shows a list of at least 30 or 40 different results of which the user must select one. The problem is that when I scroll through the search, the following error appears in the Chrome console. [Intervention] The defective passive listening of events can not be avoided because the target is treated as passive. I want to know how to correct that error? What if it is done in typed or angular css? I am using version 18.2.7 of DevExtreme.

Comment: would u please ask question in english?

Comment: Sure! I've already edited it

Comment: You missed the title :)

Comment: ready, an apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Devextreme to 18.2.8.
The issue has been resolved fairly recently but it is fixed now :)

Mentionned here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T735152/scroll-the-unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener-due-to-target-being

*(If you're still having issues after updating, check [this link too](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T733081/the-unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener-due-to-target-being-treated)))*

Comment: Excellent, update the version of DevExtreme to 19.1 and the typescript to version 3.4.5 and my problem was solved. Thank you